# Validation with rx-java2: get first error

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm trying to use rx-java to parallel validate a big file and return as soon as any validation error occurs.
My code looks like:

```
Observable<ValidationError> observable = Observable.fromIterable(lines).flatMap(
line -> Observable
            .just(line)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map(lineParser::parse)
            .map(lineValidator::validator)    //validation returns Optional<ValidationError>
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
);
```

This results in an Observable with any error in the file, but I wonder how I could make it so computation stops at the first ocurrence.
I've seen there's a blockingFirst method which seems like it would return the first error, but it's supposed to throw an Exception when no errors are found in the file, which would turn my code ugly.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to validate some input `lines` and your validator method returns `Observable<ValidationError>` . You need to get an error when any of your input validation fails , otherwise the validation is passed.

In such a scenario, your validator method can return a `Completable` instead of `Observable<ValidationError>` (where you expect the first error happened), which makes more sense

A `Completable` contract has 2 callbacks `onComplete` and `onError`. In your case, if all inputs are valid, it can trigger an `onComplete` signal. 
Otherwise, if any of the items fail, it can stop the process there and trigger an `error` signal.

The `ValidationError` can extend throwable

```
    private class ValidationError extends Throwable {

    }
```

And you can use your existing code with a slight change like this

```
    private Completable validateLines(List<String> lines) {
            return Observable.fromIterable(lines)                
                          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                          .map(lineParser::parse)
                          .map(lineValidator::validator)    //validation returns Optional<ValidationError>
                          .flatMapCompletable(optional -> optional.isPresent() ? Completable.error(new ValidationError()) : Completable.complete()); // Throw an error whenever a validation error is present , else continue
        }
```

and finaly , to perform the validation

```
     validateLines(lines)
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // if validation succeeds , on Complete is triggered
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // if any error happens , onError triggered, 
              if(e instanceof ValidationError){
                  // a validation error has happened
              }

        }
    })
```

Comment: It works perfectly and the onComplete/onError treatments looks clearer, thanks.